# WSE 2.0 SP2 on VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-services, .net-3.5, wse

Is it possible to use WSE 2.0 SP2 under VS 2008?

I realise that the add-in (that generates the proxy classes/configuration) is not compatible but there are work-arounds to this (copying over the files from a VS 2003 solution). Our web services are relatively static so would not be making too many changes anwyay.

We may at a future date move to WCF but taking baby-steps at the moment and want to get our existing services running under all the .NET 3.5 goodness.

Comment: WSE is obsolete. All new web service work should be done using WCF, and existing WSE code should be migrated or retired ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use WSE 2.0 SP3 instead of SP2. Here is why: if you care about (or pay for) Microsoft support services for your application then [SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=8070E1DE-22E1-4C78-AB9F-07A7FCF1B6AA&displaylang=en) is supported under the .NET 2.0 framework. I think there were some incompatibilities between SP2 & SP3 but the big thing is Microsoft specifically states that SP3 is supported on the .NET 2.0 framework. See the WSE 2.0 SP2 [documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=FC5F06C5-821F-41D3-A4FE-6C7B56423841&displaylang=en) and notice that it doesn't say .NET 2.0 is supported.

It looks like you want to convert/rewrite your app in the .NET 3.5 framework. Both .NET 2.0 & .NET 3.5 run under the same CLR 2.0 (yup, it's very confusing: a big thank you goes out to MS marketing!) so you probably are OK running WSE 2.0 SP3 with a.NET 3.5 app. But again, it not a supported configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to use WSE2 under VS2005/.NET 2.0 with no problems, but I dont know specifically about 2008. I needed Dime attachments (java web service - ugh.. what a headache) which are only in WSE2.

To get the functionality in VS, I actually installed WSE3 and then just changed the dll referenced in the application to the WebServices2 file and all of the Imports (VB - using c#) statements. After that, it worked like a charm.

Comment: out of interest were you using WSE 2.0 with SP and if so which one?

Comment: I dont believe I had a SP'ed version

Answer (score 0):

I have not had any issues running wse2 with visual studio 2008 as long as your just using it like a library even after I switched to the 3.5 framework.  But as you state the addin tools don't work.